# Div content is wider than parent

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

Hi I am building a rails app to display some links horizontally. They're displaying horizontally, no wrapping as I expect. However the div is much wider than the content inside..

markup:

```
<div id="timeline-container">
  <% @timeline.reverse.each do |p| %>
    <div id='timeline-item'>
      <ul>
        <% if p.class == RSpotify::Playlist %>
          <li><%= link_to image_tag(p.images[0]['url'], id: p.name.to_s, class: "playlist-cover", title: p.tracks_added_at[p.tracks_added_at.keys[0]], height:"10%", width:"10%"), {:controller => 'playlists', :action => 'timeline', :playlist => p.name, :user => @user.to_hash, :offset => 0}, class: "timeline-item" %></li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to image_tag(p[1].album.images[0]['url'], class: "track-cover", title: p[0].title.to_s, height: "15%", width:"15%"), {:controller => 'playlists', :action => 'timeline', :playlist => p[0].playlist_name, :user => @user.to_hash, :offset => 0}, id:p[0].title, class: "timeline-item" %></li>
        <% end %>
        <li><p id='moment-id'>fuck</p></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <hr size="100"/>
</div>
```

css:

```
div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width:fit-content;
}
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
table {
  display:inline-block;
  width:fit-content;
}

#timeline-item {
  width:fit-content;
  display:inline-block;
}

#timeline-container{
  display:inline-block;
}

#moment-id {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Screenshot:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSNaM.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `display: flex` to your `#timeline-container` to make all its children display horizontally.

```css
div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width:fit-content;
}
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
table {
  display:inline-block;
  width:fit-content;
}


#moment-id {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}

#timeline-container{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

#timeline-item {
  flex: 1;
}

#timeline-item img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="timeline-container">
  <div id='timeline-item'>
    <ul>
      <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" /></li>
      <li>
        <p id='moment-id'>fudge</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id='timeline-item'>
    <ul>
      <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" /></li>
      <li>
        <p id='moment-id'>fudge</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<hr size="100" />
```

Comment: OK yes thank you, that worked. Now everything is just very small. How would I increase the size of the timeline-items?

Comment: When I change height and width, they all end up on top of eachother.

Comment: @lehermj I updated the answer, please check. Basically the size of each flex-box is depending on its contents, so increasing the size of the image should do the trick. But if you want the content fully fill all the space as much as possible, you can follow by the updated answer.

Comment: Ok I made those changes and I understand how to change the sizes. However each box overlaps on the other. When I add padding, everything spazzes out.

Comment: @lehermj Can you recreate it in `jsfiddle` or `CodePen`? Not sure why that happens, must me some other css property messed them around.

Comment: yea I cleaned up my CSS, added padding to timeline-item and they no longer overlap. Just a problem on my end. Thank you for your help!